# First pair of numbers adding to a specific value in a stream

Tags: algorithm, stream

There are a stream of integers coming through. The problem is to find the **first** pair of numbers from the stream that adds to a specific value (say, k).

With static arrays, one can use either of the below approaches:

- Approach (1): Sort the array, use two pointers to beginning and end of array and compare.
- Approach (2): Use hashing, i.e. if A[i]+A[j]=k, then A[j]=k-A[i]. Search for A[j] in the hash table.

But neither of these approaches scale well for streams. Any thoughts on efficiently solving this?

Comment: what's wrong with the hash table?

Comment: Well, we'd have to hash this huge stream of numbers for one. Secondly, for every element, I need to keep searching for its pair since it's possible that the pair has not yet appeared in the stream yet. I however agree that the hashing approach is more scalable than the sorting technique.

Comment: you can build the hash as you process the stream and stop at the first pair.

Comment: any more characteristics on the numbers? Are they all in a certain range or something?

Comment: @Nick: No restrictions but I'm curious to know what you'd have to say if they were in a specific range?

Comment: @yi_H: That's true. Just wanted to see if they was any "clever" way of doing this :)

Comment: I was thinking more about some way to model the numbers to save up space... for example if there is a high probability of having sequences of numbers, you could just save intervals...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that there is no way to do this that doesn't use at least O(n) memory, where n is the number of elements that appear before the first pair that sums to k.  I'm assuming that we are using a RAM machine, but not a machine that permits awful bitwise hackery (in other words, we can't do anything fancy with bit packing.)

The proof sketch is as follows.  Suppose that we don't store all of the n elements that appear before the first pair that sums to k.  Then when we see the nth element, which sums with some previous value to get k, there is a chance that we will have discarded the previous element that it pairs with and thus won't know that the sum of k has been reached.  More formally, suppose that an adversary could watch what values we were storing in memory as we looked at the first n - 1 elements and noted that we didn't store some element x.  Then the adversary could set the next element of the stream to be k - x and we would incorrectly report that the sum had not yet been reached, since we wouldn't remember seeing x.

Given that we need to store all the elements we've seen, without knowing more about the numbers in the stream, a very good approach would be to use a hash table that contains all of the elements we've seen so far.  Given a good hash table, this would take expected O(n) memory and O(n) time to complete.

I am not sure whether there is a more clever strategy for solving this problem if you make stronger assumptions about the sorts of numbers in the stream, but I am fairly confident that this is asymptotically ideal in terms of time and space.

Hope this helps!

Comment: You make a valid point. I wanted to see if there was a smarter way of solving this problem other than the 2 approaches I outlined. I was trying to see if we could cash in on the "first pair of numbers" part of the question but guess not.